# How to prevent Java developers from using new language features?

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

Since Java SE 7 is [EOL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html), upgrading to Java 8 is necessary. However there are business reasons to not allow the developers to use any of the new language features. The feature that is especially forbidden is lambdas.

How can the use of Java 7 features be enforced? The build system is based on Jenkins and there is also SonarQube available.

Comment: Compile with `javac -source 1.7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers are partially right. Compiler must indeed be configured with -source 1.7 to check that no Java 8 lang features are used. But it does not prevent from using the new Java 8 APIs. A solution is to use the animal sniffer project to verify that only Java 7 APIs are used.

Here is a a sample of configuration for maven projects:

```
 <build>   
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>enforce-java-api-compatibility</id>
                  <phase>verify</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>check</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <signature>
                          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature
                          </groupId>
                          <artifactId>java17</artifactId>
                          <version>1.0</version>
                      </signature>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to ensure they haven't used any JDK 8 features and broken backwards compatibility is to compile the source code for 1.7

For example

```
javac -source 1.7
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

if you use eclipse or idea, you could set the compiler level to 1.7, even when you use jdk8. then the ide will error out any new features.